# How to create a button that does not respond to multitouch in Unity for iOS?

Tags: ios, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I have an issue. I am creating a iOS game in Unity and I have a standard UI button that the player is supposed to tap as fast as possible. Though when the player tap the button with 2 fingers, simultaneously, it registers as two taps... 3 taps with 3 fingers and so on. How can I get the button to only register one tap, even when the player taps with 3 fingers simultaneously?

Comment: How are you currently detecting the click on the button?

Comment: @Programmer I simply have an UI button In a Canvas. In the Hierarchy: RightClick -> UI -> Button. Then the Button Script has an OnClick() that calls a method in another Script on the Button GameObject.

Comment: If two touches are pressed on the button at the-same time, it should count as one or don't count at-all? What if one finger is already on the button but not released then another finger is used to do a press, should that count as a press to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variable to avoid multiple touches if you arent using touch phase

**if Checking mousedown:**

```
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)&& !pressed){
       pressed =true
       //Do if pressed
    } 
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)){
        pressed =false
    }
```

**If checking touch phases**

```
     if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began){//This will only call your 1st touch when it begins 
     //Do Your thing 
     }
```

**IF using onMouseDown**

```
  onMouseDown(){
    if(pressed){return;}
    pressed=true;
  }
  onMouseUp(){
  pressed =false;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick that i do is create a transparent image object and place it below my buttons UI, then attach my gestures script to that image, hope that it helps